# Function expects type Dictionary.key = string instead IntSet

Tags: dictionary, functional-programming, set, ocaml

[image]

Hello, I have this exercise to do:
Write a function that receives a string-to-integer dictionary and a list of strings and
returns the set of all values in the dictionary that match the strings in the list.
Loop through the list with List.fold_left. When using find, handle the Not_found exception for a
add a value to the accumulator-set only when the key is found in the dictionary.

I do not understand why the interpreter expects Dictionary.key = string instead of set of int ? Where is the little thing am I missing ?

Comment: Please post the code and error message as _text_, not as an image: See [ask] and more specifically https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As @glennsl points out, it's very difficult to comment on your code when you post only a picture of it. I have to retype any parts I want to talk about. You should post the code itself, and the compiler error message, as text.)

Here is the type of List.fold left:

```
# List.fold_left;;
- : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a = <fun>
```

The folded function takes the accumulated result and an element of the list, in that order.

The function you're folding is defined like this:

```
fun elt res ->
```

If I go by the names, it seems like you have the paramegers backwards. I.e., your function expects the list element to be the first parameter.

I'm not sure this is causing your problem, but it definitely bears looking into.